# How to select lowest value for each subject?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
subject_ID    Date     Test_id  value
-------     ---------   -----  -----
   1          1/1/2000     A     50
   1          1/1/2000     B     10
   1          1/2/2000     A     55
   1          1/2/2000     B     09
   2          1/1/2000     A     51
   2          1/1/2000     B     13
   2          1/2/2000     A     48
   2          1/2/2000     B     08
```

Hi All,

I have a question about the scenario above. As you see I have test results that comes daily for each subjects. I'm trying to find a way to select the lowest value for  each test in defined period of time so final table will be like this

```
subject_ID    Date     Test_id  value
-------     ---------   -----  -----
  1          1/1/2000    A      50
  1          1/2/2000    B      09
  2          1/2/2000    A      48
  2          1/2/2000    B      08
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what technology you are using, but assuming SQL something using a GROUP BY will work.

```
SELECT subject_ID    
    , Date     
    , Test_id
    , MIN(value)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY subject_ID    
    , Date     
    , Test_id
```

Comment: Are you sure about grouping by Test_id?? I think it will not yield the desire output, which is the lowest score, no matter on which test.

Comment: The question says "the lowest value for each test".

Comment: So this works only if I deselect the date because when I grouped by date it showed the original table because my understanding this will get the least value of the test in that date. The question is how can I go without grouping by date. It just keep saying I must include it in group by clause. I use Postgres sql 9.

Comment: I now see what you (@user2332760) wanted to achieve. You are looking for the lowest score of each test regardless of the date. In that case just remove "Date" from the GROUP BY, as you already figured out. Note that this will not work if you are looking for the lowest score for each subject for every month (or any other period of time)

Comment: @ Tal J. Levy, That's correct but the question is there any way to get the date for each value?

Comment: I don't have Postgres available, but you can accomplish what you are trying to do with a "With Query", also known as a CTE. Stick the group by query (without the date) into a WITH query and name it something. Then in your outer query you can join that query against YourTable and pull out whatever other columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI standard SQL supports the `row_number()` function.  With this function, you ca do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by subject_id, test_id order by value asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```